# Unable to launch my own bundle with composer

Tags: php, service, bundle, symfony4

I am working with symfony4 and I want to create and use my own bundle.

I have created my own bundle following the tutorial: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-bundle

I am encoutering a problem at the **Chapter 09: Proper Bundle composer.json File**.

I have followed all steps of this chapter. I've tried to launch the command `composer require bon-coin-bundle:*@dev` as indicated, but here are my errors:

- "bon-coin-bundle" is not a valid alias. Did you mean this:
  "symfony/monolog-bundle", supported aliases: "monolog-bundle"

Thus I tried to launch other commands without better results: `composer require ../bon-coin-bundle:*`, `composer require ../bon-coin-bundle:*@dev`  ...

I've edited the composer.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "bon-coin-bundle",
    "description": "Bon Coin",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "matodo",
            "email": "matodo@xxx.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "bonCoinBundle\\": "bonCoinBundle"
        }
    }
}
```

(I am not really sure of what I've done for the autoload part, but I don't think that the problem comes frome there)

My folders are ranked like this: a bonCoinBundle folder contains DependencyInjections, Resources and services for my bundle. 
The folder bonCoinBundle is not in my current projet symfony.

```
bonCoinBundle
|- DependencyInjection
   Resources
   ...
symfonyProject
|- src 
   ...
```

Comment: Did you post your bundle to packagist or set bundle's repository in project's composer.json?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what means posting a bundle to packagist,  but I've put this path in project's composer.json :

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../bonCoinBundle"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I've found my error, I was not in dev! I have add  "minimum-stability": "dev" in the both composer, and  it fixed my errors